# Asignar un color a cada ítem dentro de un cardview

Tags: android, array

tengo un `cardview` en un `activity` en total son 6 y deseo asignarle un color diferente a cada `cardview`. El problema es que no le puedo asignar dicho color. He creado un `array`en `colors.XML`

```
 <integer-array name="initial_colors">
<item>@color/red</item>
<item>@color/indigo</item>
<item>@color/deep_purple</item>
<item>@color/light_green</item>
<item>@color/teal</item>
<item>@color/pink</item>
</integer-array>
  <item name="red" type="color">#f44336</item>
<item name="indigo" type="color">#3f51b5</item>
<item name="deep_purple" type="color">#673ab7</item>
<item name="light_green" type="color">#689f38</item>
<item name="teal" type="color">#009688</item>
<item name="pink" type="color">#e91e63</item>
```

El asunto es **como asignar** estos colores a cada ítem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te falto :

```
int[] initial_colors = context.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.initial_colors);

for (int i = 0; i < tus_datos; i++) {
   paint.setColor(initial_colors[i]);

}
```

O tambien puedes hacerlo de esta manera dentro del RecyclerAdapter :

```
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
if(position==1)
   holder.view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
else if(position==2)
   holder.view.setBackgroundColor(COLOR.BLUE);
}
```

El `view` debes reemplazarlo por tu `TextView` o el elemento que quieras pintar

Comment: Este ira en el RecyclerAdapter  o en el MainActivity ?

Comment: donde cargas tus datos para el cardview?

Comment: En el RecyclerAdapter cargo una imageView y el TextView para el Cardview

Comment: hazlo ahi, en el metodo onCreateViewHolder

Comment: El paint. signifca?

Comment: Paint paint = new Paint();

Comment: entiendo, sin embargo en el holder,view marca en rojo el View

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50545/discussion-between-sioesi-and-felix-beeb).